# How to upgrade node version of instance in AWS OpsWorks

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

I am using AWS OpsWorks to run my instance.And for the instance I am using, I could only select node version till 0.12.12. How would I create an instance with a higher node version? In this case, I want that to be above 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

To Create an Instance with a Higher Node Version:

You Can Create a **Custom Layer** in AWS OpsWork with a **custom CookBook** with the version you need.

Once you launch instances under your custom layer, Your instances inherit the configuration of the new custom layer with the **New Version**.

Comment: Could you give more information? I am using https://github.com/redguide/nodejs.git but don't understand how to setup a specific nodejs version.